# background image missing from iPad on form select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a select form control with a custom down arrow image displayed on the right. This image doesn't display when viewing on an iPad. Does anyone know what I am missing? This is the HTML I have and CSS code I included aside from Bootstrap 3.0

```
<form name="scmarketer" id="scmarketer" action="" class="form-inline">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>John Smith - Ontario CA</option>
        <option>Jane Smith - Ontario CA</option>
        <option>Brandon Smith - Ontario CA</option>
        <option>Terrell Owens - Ontario CA</option>
        <option>John Smith - Ontario CA</option>
        <option>Jane Smith - Ontario CA</option>
        <option>Brandon Smith - Ontario CA</option>
        <option>Terrell Owens - Ontario CA</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>

select.form-control {
    background-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 70%;
    @media (max-width: 789px) {
        width:100%;
    }
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
    background-image: url('../images/dropdown.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image URL is set to "../images/dropdown.png" so it will only work on your local computer. Hence, you need to set this to the location of your image.

Comment: You were close, my code was correct but I had forgotten to upload the dropdown.png image to my server. LOL thanks

Comment: I wouldn't use ... for the image URL as there's no need for it.

Comment: BTW, it's common standard to alphabetize the different CSS styles for an element so it's easier to find what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this:

```
@media (max-width: 789px) {
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This didn't make any difference